# Responding with error using RABL template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rabl

I am building a JSON API and so far I didn't find a good advice on how to handle save errors in controllers that use RABL templates. I'd really appreciate any advise on improving the code.

Here's how I currently handle a failure to save:

```
    # products_controller.rb
    def create
      @product = Product.new(params[:product])
      unless @product.save
        render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
```

And here's my RABL template:

```
    # product.json.rabl
    object @product
    attributes :name, :price
```

It works, but the line 'unless @product.save' doesn't feel right... Here are the tests:

```
    # products_controller_test.rb
    test 'create a product' do
      assert_difference 'Product.count', 1 do
        post :create, product: { name: 'Apple', price: 1.25 }, format: :json
      end
      assert_response :success
    end

    test 'failing product creation' do
      Product.any_instance.stubs(:save).returns(false)
      assert_no_difference 'Product.count' do
        post :create, product: { name: 'Apple' }, format: :json
      end
      assert_response 422
    end
```

**Update**

Thanks to @KonradOleksiuk I was able to rewrite the controller in a more readable way:

```
    if @product.save
      respond_with @product
    else
      respond_with @product, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
```

I also had to make sure errors were getting attached to the json response:

```
    # product.json.rabl
    object @product
    attributes :name, :price

    node :errors do |o|
      o.errors
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on format you would like to achieve in response. You can always use `node` in rabl template to render errors inline. It has already been explained by collaborator of the gem: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/222#issuecomment-5413021

Thanks to this you can avoid the unless statement and use only view.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad! Does it mean you need to check on the front end if the json error attribute is not null to see if error has occured? If I understand it correctly the response status is 200 (:ok) in both cases?

Comment: With explicit render method - yes. But you can use respond_with method, which will return 422 in case errors object is present - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html (Custom options header)

Comment: thanks for the respond_with hint. Can't upvote your solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
   @product.save
   respond_with @product
end
```

Works in both cases for success and failed save.
If save fails respond_with will render json with @product errors, in success case it will render rabl template

Comment: I'm afraid the status code will be 200 :ok in both success and failure cases.

Comment: no, in failure case code is 422 Unprocessable Entity